# how do i plot contourf given no relationship between X, Y and Z variables?

Tags: matlab, contourf

I have a dataset in which I would want to plot in matlab. The main dataset is the result of the differences between two angles `(Øact - Øcalc)` obtained from analytical and experimental results at `specific analytical angles (Øact: 20, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 100 degrees)`. These simple calculations were made for varying `search radiuses (5 – 25%)` at different `resolutions (14 – 224 pixels/diameter)`.

What I would want to do is to plot the angular difference (for each specified angle) as a function of both search radius and resolution. i.e.

`Øact – Øcalc = f(search radius, resolution)`

I am told that I could do this with `contourf()`, but I am inundated as to how to apply the function to my data as i am not sure how to relate my `Z to the X and Y grids`. In any case, I have tried the following code:

```
SR  = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25];
res = [14, 28, 56, 112, 224];

angle_diff =  [70, 25, 25, 11, 6.6
               25, 25, 11, 6.6, 6.6
               43.4, 25, 15.5, 11, 10.4
               25, 25, 17.9, 12.3, 12.3
               36.3, 25, 19.3, 16.5, 14.8];


 x = linspace(min(SR), max(SR), 5);
 y = linspace(min(res), max(res), 5);

 [X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);


% not sure what to do here


 [C, h] = contourf(X, Y, angle_diff);
 clabel(C,h)
```

However, I am not sure what to do in between the `meshgrid()` and `contourf()` so as to bring in the values of `angle_diff`

[image]

[image]

Please, I need any help/suggestions/reference/advice as to how I could get around this.

An excel spreadsheet of my data for all other angles will be similar to the the figure attached:

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you want your plot to look like? Do you want a separate line for each search radius or do you want a 2D "heatmap"?

Comment: @Suever: either will be fine but i won't mind seeing both so i could choose which looks best. Many thanks!

Comment: There are about 100000 ways to plot this data. Please show us what you want and what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have seen the documentation for the contour plots, but like my post reads, i am still inundated as to how to apply this to my dataset which is why i need someone to help me with some direction to follow. I actually have never had to make these kind of plots before.

Comment: The plot above is for a single analytical angle, but what i would want is to have a series of lines (possibly) for each specified angle.

Answer (score 0):

Now i had to pretty much enter the values manually to get something out of this. Hence, I won't mind if there is a better suggestion.

```
% for angle 20 deg.
X = [5 5 5 5 5              % search radius
    10 10 10 10 10
    15 15 15 15 15
    20 20 20 20 20
    25 25 25 25 25];

Y = [14 28 56 112 224       % Resolution
    14 28 56 112 224
    14 28 56 112 224
    14 28 56 112 224
    14 28 56 112 224];

Z = [70 25 25 11 6.6        % theta(act) - theta(calc)
    25 25 11 6.6 6.6
    43.5 25 15.5 11 10.4
    25 25 17.9 12.3 12.3
    36.3 25 19.3 16.5 14.8];

[C, h] = contourf(X, Y, Z, 20);
clabel(C,h)
title('For analytical angle = 20\circ')

c = colorbar;
c.Label.String   = '\thetaact - \thetacalc [\circ]';
c.Label.FontSize = 11;

xlabel('Search radius [% droplet diameter]', 'fontsize',11)
ylabel('Resolution [pixel/diameter]', 'fontsize',11)
```